# definition of foliation in manifold and why foliation is useful?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am thinking for the simple definition of **"foliation"** for a manifold. Why foliation is useful in manifold theory?

Comment: Are you asking for the definition? If so, [Wikipedia has the answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation).

Comment: I am looking for a simple definition

Answer (score 6):

Roughly speaking, a codimension $n-q$ foliation $F$ on an $n$-manifold $M$  is partition of $M$ in $q$-manifolds, called leaves, such that locally $M$ is a product $R^{q}\times R^{n-q}$.  Foliations are useful because  they can give information about the topological structure of the manifold. For example a non-singular foliation on a 2-manifold $M$ implies that $M$ is the torus or the Klein bottle. A special case of a foliation is a non-singular flow, which serves as model for some physical systems.

Comment: I assume the $2$-manifold $M$ is compact?

Comment: @JesseMadnick I agree. Otherwise, as it is said on Fantasy Island: "Lookit the plane, boss, lookit the plane!"